# What does it mean , Illegal instruction: 4?

Tags: swift

Below is the small code snippet written in swift,gives below error, although looking at code nothing seems wrong.

Fatal error: Index out of range
Illegal instruction: 4

Not clear to me what is the exact cause of problem ? Would be really helpful if someone can share insights on it.

```
func getBinary(ValueInDecimal:Int) -> [Int]
{
    var valueToPlayWith = ValueInDecimal

    var aryBinary = [Int]()

    var i:Int = 0

    while valueToPlayWith != 0 {

        aryBinary[i] = valueToPlayWith % 2
        valueToPlayWith = valueToPlayWith / 2
        i = i + 1
    }

    return aryBinary
}

// calling of function 

let aryBin = getBinary(ValueInDecimal:10)

print(aryBin)
```

Expected answer is binary value of passed decimal number in array of 0s and 1s.

So I think if I will use it like this then syntax array[i] = value will work.

```
func getBinary(ValueInDecimal:Int) -> [Int:Int]
{
    var valueToPlayWith = ValueInDecimal

    var aryBinary = [Int:Int]()

    var i:Int = 0

    while valueToPlayWith != 0 {

        aryBinary[i] = valueToPlayWith % 2
        valueToPlayWith = valueToPlayWith / 2
        i = i + 1
    }

    return aryBinary
}

let aryBin = getBinary(ValueInDecimal:10)

print(aryBin)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an empty array

```
var aryBinary = [Int]()
```

so this will crash as index 0  doesn't exist

```
aryBinary[i] = valueToPlayWith % 2
```

> Fatal error: Index out of range

You may need

```
func getBinary(_ valueInDecimal:Int) -> [Int] {

    var valueToPlayWith = valueInDecimal 
    var aryBinary = [Int]() 
    while valueToPlayWith != 0 { 
        aryBinary.append(valueToPlayWith % 2) 
        valueToPlayWith = valueToPlayWith / 2 
    } 
    return aryBinary
}


let aryBin = getBinary(10)

print(aryBin)  /// [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Ohh it is my silly mistake , I used array like dictionary, yeah  I should use append here to add new values. Thanks.

Comment: Check my edit , so it will work if I change the return type to dictionary with same code.

Comment: yes,it'll work the dictionary is different than the array